# Interface not getting changed - winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I have a function, when the function starts, I want to display some UI components and then start working and at the end, I want to erase those components from there. Problem is that I don't see the change in UI on the form.

The function in which I am doing this is:

```
public void Processor()
{
    // ------------- SETTING UI COMPONENTS 

    lblProgress.Visible = true;
    progressBar.Visible = true;
    btnStop.Visible = true;

    // ------------- WORKING

    int counter = 0, percent = 0;
    foreach (string url in Urls)
    {
        .... WORKING THAT TAKES TIME

        counter += 1;
        percent = ((counter * 100) / Urls.Count());

        // ------------- MODIFYING UI COMPONENTS
        // Modification doesn't appear on the form while running

        lblProgress.Text = "Progress: " + (percent > 100 ? 100 : percent) + "%";
        progressBar.Value = percent;
    }

    // ------------- SETTING UI COMPONENTS

    lblProgress.Visible = false;
    progressBar.Visible = false;
    btnStop.Visible = false;
    lblDone.Visible = true;
}
```

Can someone help with this. Kindly let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I have total 1066 URL, each URL takes around 6s of processor.

Comment: Try to use Application.DoEvents() after you write to the controls.

Comment: @user2831683 Although you seem to like the answer below, it is not as good as you think. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5183623/932418 Solution: using Tasks, async/await.

Comment: Please do **not** use `.DoEvents()`. See my comment on Vimalan's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@user2831683, I think you know now that using *Application.DoEvents* is not much advisable.  Here is another alternative you can use:

```
async public void Processor() //see the "async" keyword
{
   //SETTING UI COMPONENTS 

   foreach (string url in Urls)
   {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
             //.... WORKING THAT TAKES TIME

        });

        //MODIFYING UI COMPONENTS
   }
}
```

While `DoEvents` makes your code seem to work, your UI is still blocked by your *work* most of the time. This approach will allow your UI to make more *smooth* updates (for ex, while moving your window etc.)

PS: The only change in the original code is the part `//.... WORKING THAT TAKES TIME`,  which is replaced by a *Task*

Comment: Yes, this is another good approach - however I think you need to show how the progress bar would get updated as code within the task would need to marshal back to the UI thread.

Comment: @Enigmativity Just the same in question. No extra code is needed.  I don't see any problem, if the OP doesn't access any UI components in his *working* block.

Comment: The working of the task doesn't manipulate the UI components. As far I understand it might be that the working of the task makes the processor busy for which the UI components get in the block queue and don't respond.

Comment: @user2831683 All of the UI updates are handled by a single thread. If you keep it busy, your interface will be unresponsive. This is the whole idea.

Comment: @EZI - The OP is updating a progress bar inside the loop. That needs to be done on the UI thread.

Comment: @Enigmativity And my code does so (without any extra code) . This is the trick of using async/await

Comment: @EZI - Sorry, you're right. You've shelled out the code and I was not mentally rebuilding it properly. It might be worth putting back the OP's UI update bits to show explicitly where they go.

Comment: @Enigmativity I posted it like this just to be able to point out the *await* code. Otherwise It could have been lost in "unrelated codes for this answer"....

Answer (score 3):

As an addition to Vimalan's response:

`Application.DoEvents()` forces to pump the message on the windows message queue. This means that any pending request(s) for UI update are invoked via `Application.DoEvents()` so this is a brute-force method. I would suggest to make your UI responsive by removing the block of code which is taking time to process and run it on a seprate thread. Right now the code that takes time is also running on the main thread (where the UI is running too.) which I would say choke the main thread and is heaving difficulty to swallow and digest it ;)

Try reading the following asynchronous programming pattern to learn more:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152938(v=vs.110).aspx

Or you can use a background worker:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Please do **not** use `.DoEvents()`. It can cause all sorts of re-entrancy issues in your code and can break third-party code. Actually it can break the built-in Windows Forms code too, depending on what you're doing.

I would certainly suggest `BackgroundWorker` as the stock standard approach to resolve this issue.

I, however, prefer to use Microsoft's Reactive Framework for this kind of thing. It makes things like this very simple.

Here's how I would have tackled this:

```
public void Processor()
{
    // ------------- SETTING UI COMPONENTS 

    lblProgress.Visible = true;
    progressBar.Visible = true;
    btnStop.Visible = true;

    // ------------- WORKING

    Urls
        .ToObservable(Scheduler.Default) // Goes to background thread
        .Do(url =>
        {
            /* .... WORKING THAT TAKES TIME */
        })
        .Select((url, counter) => counter * 100 / Urls.Count())
        .DistinctUntilChanged()
        .ObserveOn(this) // back to the UI thread
        .Subscribe(
            percent => // Done each change in percent
            {
                lblProgress.Text = "Progress: " + (percent > 100 ? 100 : percent) + "%";
                progressBar.Value = percent;
            },
            () => // Done when finished processing
            {
                lblProgress.Visible = false;
                progressBar.Visible = false;
                btnStop.Visible = false;
                lblDone.Visible = true; 
            });
}
```

You can NuGet "Rx-WinForms" to get all of this goodness.